# How to get pixel color from a Point in image with WriteableBitmapEx in WinRT?

Tags: windows-runtime, writeablebitmapex, win-universal-app

I'm porting my current (Silverlight) WP8.0 app to a Universal Windows application. In this application I have a control that allows the user to use a custom dial control. When the dial stops, the app should get the pixel color from that specific point (and underlaying image).

In WP8.0, I used to do the following:

```
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(ColorWheelImage, null);
Color c = wb.GetPixel(pointX, pointY);
```

ColorWheelImage is in the XAML.

In WinRT the WriteableBitmap only support `new WriteableBitmap(int pixelWidth, int pixelWidth)` and not setting an image like in Silverlight.

How can I fix this.. I can't seem to figure it out :(!

Thanks,
Niels

Comment: @chuex it's not a duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WinRT, `WriteableBitmap` is unable to draw visuals. Instead, MS added new control `RenderTargetBitmap`.

```
RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(); 
await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(ColorWheelImage, width, height);
IBuffer pixelBuffer = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
```

But `GetPixelsAsync()` gives you `IBuffer`, instead of int array. To get an ordinal `WriteableBitmap`, you can use [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/).

```
var width = renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth;
var height = renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight;
var writeableBitmap = await new WriteableBitmap(1, 1).FromPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer, width, height);
```